# How is a connection kept opened at the physical layer level

Tags: sockets, http, networking

I'm having a difficult time understanding the concept of persisent connection.

If we take as an example the Http protocol using the keep-alive header, after tcp/ip performing the handshake along with the necessary validations, the connection is kept alive for x ms, allowing the user to send multiple requests using the same connection/port. The impact of a persistent connection is clear to me, at least at this level of understanding, overhead is reduced.

- However, what I cannot seem to understand is how does this connection
  is kept alive at physical level. Is it at logical or physical level and how ?
- If it is at logical level, the message to be sent will already
  contain the headers with information from the performed handshakes
  and validations so it will skip through the steps involved in finding
  the target physical address and other router related actions on the
  packet including http handshake and so on ?
- While a connection is alive, will there be any control (ping) messages
  sent between source and destination to see if they are still there ?

Regards

Comment: TCP connections exists on the logical layer not the physical. You need to read the basics of TCP (how a connections is established with a 3-way handshake and how it is teared down). Then if you still are puzzled come back with a more specific question (there are too many `?` in this one :-)

Comment: [tag:osi] doesn't apply to anything in the real world, certainly not HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical layer doesn't know any "open connection". It works on bits or packets alone and just transports bits from one end of a link to the other.

A logical connection becomes only possible much higher up the stack where TCP (or a similar protocol) uses the lower layers to simulate a connection that really isn't there in packet-switched networks.

Within a single logical connection, completely different routes = physical paths can be used without the transport layer even noticing.

Whether or not a transport layer protocol (or application layer protocol for that matter) uses some kind of keep-alive or not is entirely up to the protocol. Most often, a connection is closed when there's been no transmission for a certain period (timeout) so you don't end up with a bunch of zombie sockets.